# Checking if dialog isOpen throws "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using a dialog and checking it with the code that i found in the docs

```
var isOpen = $( "#dialogName" ).dialog( "isOpen" );
$("#here").on("click", function(e){
    if(isOpen){
        $("#dialogName").dialog("close");
    } 
});
```

Sometimes I get the error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'close'

And sometimes that it can't find isOpen. What i want to do is:

On click `#here` it must check if the dialog is alive then `close` otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isOpen` is a method called on an existing dialog, while the dialog has not been yet initialized.

You should initialize the dialog first, then inside `click` event handler check whether the dialog `isOpen` currently.

```
// initialize the dialog:
var myDialog = $( "#dialogName" ).dialog({
    // dialog settings:
    autoOpen : false,
    // ... 
});

$("#here").on("click", function(e){
    // on click, check if is opened:
    var isOpen = myDialog.dialog("isOpen");
    if(isOpen){
       myDialog.dialog("close");
    } 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7ehcs3w/)

Answer (score 9):

Seems like you also need to check if `#dialogName` has been *dialogified*. One possible way to check is to look at the class names assigned to the dialog element:

```
$("#dialog").hasClass("ui-dialog-content") && $("#dialog").dialog("isOpen")
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#init").one("click", function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $(this).val("Click to open dialog").on("click", function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
  });
  $("#here").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($("#dialog").hasClass("ui-dialog-content") && $("#dialog").dialog("isOpen")) {
      $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    } else {
      alert("Dialog not initialized or dialog not open");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog title" style="display: none;">Dialog content</div>

<input type="button" id="init" value="Click to create dialog">
<input type="button" id="here" value="Click to close dialog">
```